# Edit button on JQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am displaying a data using JQuery DataTable, and I want to make a edit button for each rows in that table.

However, I have 2 problems which regarding that button.

```
 1. Once I run the application, the Edit button will trigger automatically (which redirect to the new page).
 2. I want to get the information of the first column of the selected row, but what I got is undefined value.
```

Here is the code that I am using:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tblMember">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#tblMember').dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            sAjaxSource: "~/MemberService.ashx",
            fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "GroupAccount", "value": "Account" })

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: aoData,
                    url: sSource,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg);

                        $("#tblMember").dataTable().show();
                    }
                });
            },
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    className: "dt-body-center",
                    targets: -1,
                    data: "Name",
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<button onclick='" + GetSelectedData(data) + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    function GetSelectedData(value) {
        window.location = "~/Registration.aspx?Name='" + value + "'";
    }
```

What I am missing?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your edit button is getting created?

Comment: yes, it is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when I had a similar requirement I have created the button with property `columnDefs` but handled its click call outside of the `DataTable` definition.

I am providing the solution assuming your table is initializing properly except the edit button issue.

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/j3cb2bfo/5/

Adding the edit button to your table :

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        className: "dt-body-center",
        targets: -1,
        defaultContent: ["<i class='fa fa-pencil editButton' aria-hidden='true' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]

     }
 ]
```

Handling the click call of the edit button

Assuming

`var memberTable = $('#tblMember').dataTable({`

then

```
$('body').on('click', '#tblMember tbody tr .editButton', function () {
    var rowData = memberTable.row( $(this).parents('tr')).data();
    console.log("Rows data : ",  rowData);

    //fetch first column data by key if you are passing map as input to table
    console.log("First column data : ", rowData[0]); 
});
```